# How to replace value by the latest date in the column (M)

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I was trying to replace a specific value (Contagem) by the earliest date found (minus 01 day)  in column Data, but I just can't figure out how.
The idea is to set this earliest date - 1 day as an initial date for inventory count and then there'll be other days following with the movement.

```
let
    Fonte = Excel.Workbook(Web.Contents("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/hdsdshjdsh/pub?output=xlsx"), null, true),
    Previsão_Sheet = Fonte{[Item="Previsão",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Cabeçalhos Promovidos" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Previsão_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Tipo Alterado" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Cabeçalhos Promovidos",{{"Previsão de Produção", type text}, {"Column2", type any}, {"Column3", type any}, {"Column4", type text}, {"Column5", type text}, {"Column6", type any}, {"Column7", type any}, {"Column8", type any}, {"Column9", type any}, {"Column10", type any}, {"Column11", type any}, {"Column12", type any}, {"Column13", type any}, {"Column14", type any}, {"Column15", type any}, {"Column16", type any}, {"Column17", type any}, {"Column18", type any}, {"Column19", type any}, {"Column20", type any}}),
    #"Linhas Principais Removidas" = Table.Skip(#"Tipo Alterado",3),
    #"Cabeçalhos Promovidos1" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Linhas Principais Removidas", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Colunas Removidas" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Cabeçalhos Promovidos1",{"Local"}),
    #"Outras Colunas Não Dinâmicas" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Colunas Removidas", {"Und", "Descrição", "Cód.", "Categoria"}, "Atributo", "Valor"),
    #"Linhas Filtradas" = Table.SelectRows(#"Outras Colunas Não Dinâmicas", each Text.Contains([Atributo], "/") or [Atributo] = "Contagem"),
    #"Colunas Renomeadas" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Linhas Filtradas",{{"Atributo", "Data"}})
    #"Valor Substituído" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Colunas Renomeadas","Contagem","31/01/2021",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Data"})
    //#"Valor Substituído" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Colunas Renomeadas","Contagem", List.Max(Table.RemoveRowsWithErrors(#"Tipo Alterado", {"Atributo"})[Data]),Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Data"})
in
    #"Valor Substituído"
```

The last two rows are where the solution should be implemented, but...

I'd appreciate any help.

Cheers,
Antonio

Comment: Can you add some sample data? And your expected output from them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if something like this works for you

- Convert data column to text
- Remove all other columns
- Change data column to date
- Remove all rows with errors
- Get the min date using List.Min(), subtract one, convert to text with Text.From()
- Edit-replace the original Data column's  text with the new value

Sample

```
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Colunas Renomeadas",{{"Data", type text}}),
newdate= Date.AddDays(List.Min(Table.RemoveRowsWithErrors(Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table.SelectColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Data"}),{{"Data", type datetime}}), {"Data"})[Data]),-1),
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Changed Type","Contagem",Text.From(newdate),Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Data"})
in #"Replaced Value"
```

Comment: Hi! It did work until the point where I have the earliest date set in the following format: dd/mm/yyyy ##:##:## and as text. If I try to change its format to date, these dates added throw an error. Would you happen to know why? Thanks - again